# Cast object to subclass in c#

Tags: c#, oop, subclass

I've not been able to find a post on this for C#.  Is there any way to do this..

```
class parent {
    public parent() { }
}

class child : parent {
    public child() { }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        parent p = new parent();
        child c = (child)p;  
    }
}
```

The reason I want to do this is to add some methods to an object that is created by a call to a function `(UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())`.

Comment: the ony way to add methods to an object is to use either inheritance (subclass), or use extension methods, which just *look* like they are methods on an object.

Comment: Relevant: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366592/what-is-a-proper-use-of-downcasting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible. [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) works in the other direction - using a descended class as if it's the more generic parent.

It is possible, however, to add methods to existing classes. This is called an [extension method](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx&ei=8C66UePEBZL4rAGLiYCwDw&usg=AFQjCNHsL_hz8qi3KpRY9Jlee-voybqfrw&sig2=CMQAXBm4NaKa25p9j_KHaA&bvm=bv.47883778,d.dmg). It will, however, be added to all instances of the class it's written to extend.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that.

Consider the example:

```
class Fruit {
    // bla
}

class Banana : Fruit {
    // bla
}
```

The following is not possible

```
Fruit f = new Fruit();
Banana b = (Banana)f;
```

because not all fruits are Bananas

Answer (score 2):

o you cannot do this. Your declarations are that Child inherits from Parent. There is nothing saying that a Parent has to be a Child.

If you had used `Parent p = new Child()` then your cast would be okay.

If you want to add methods to an existing object then I think that you should research `Extension methods`, as they were created for the purpose of extending classes that you cannot modify.

Answer (score 0):

The instance that your base class reference is referring to is not an instance of your child class.

```
Parent c = new child();
Parent p = new parent();

Child good = (Child )c; // OK
Child fail = (Child )p; // Throws InvalidCastException
```

For the cast to be successful, the instance that you're downcasting must be an instance of the class that you're downcasting to.

In order for this to work you would have to do the following:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        parent p = new child();
        child c = (child)p;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're discussing the concept of Polymorphism. What you request is not possible. The reason is  obvious with a little explanation:

The `child` class is allowed to extend the functionality of the `parent` class however it wants... Adding tons of new methods and properties, etc... `child` is a **superset** of `parent`. So casting `parent` to `child` would leave a portion of the superset that was not covered - there would be no defined functionality for child's new members, methods, and properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can only cast from a parent class to child class if the object first was initiated by child constructor.
This is same in all OOP languages through polymorphism.
Here you can see an example:

```
class parent {
    public parent() { }
}

class child : parent {
    public child() { }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        parent p = new child();
        child c = (child)p;  
    }
}
```

To check if an instance is initiated by a specific class you can use the oprator: `is`